# C: fscanf causes an uninitalized variable error

Tags: c, file, io, scanf

I'm trying to red in information from the snack.dat file but get this error.

warning: ‘fido_speed’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|

and so on for the rest of the int* declarations.

#### "Snack.dat"

```
10 20 5 15
19 20 20 20
1 50 1 51
10 20 10 20
0 0 0 0
```

#### Code

```
int main()
{
    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;

    const char* in_file="snack.dat";
    const char* out_file="snack.out";

    int* fido_speed;
    int* joe_speed;

    int* fido_distance;
    int* joe_distance;

    input = fopen(in_file,"r");
    output = fopen(out_file,"w");

    while(!feof(input)){

       fscanf(input,"%d %d %d %d", joe_distance, fido_distance, joe_speed, fido_speed);

        if (((*joe_distance)/(*joe_speed)) < ((*fido_distance)/(*fido_speed))){
            fprintf(output,"Fido is no longer hungry.");
        }

        else if(((*joe_distance)/(*joe_speed)) > ((*fido_distance)/(*fido_speed))){
            fprintf(output,"Joe makes it.");
        }

        else{
            fprintf(output,"/0");
        }
    };

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops!  Your pointers don't have any storage allocated to them (hence "uninitialized"):

```
int* fido_speed;
```

Is a pointer, it holds the address of an `int` type (or, if uninitialized, a junk/bogus address).  However, it does not hold the value of the int it points to.  In order to do that, you need to `malloc()` it some memory or else point it at an existing int.

In this context, it may be easier to just pass the address of a normal int to scanf:

```
int fido_speed;  // not a pointer
fscanf(input, "%d", &fido_speed);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite obvious: you're using uninitialized pointers, so you're reading data into random parts of memory. You should use `int` variables instead of `int*` stores and get pointers to them with `&`.